# View Frame Size Height = 0

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I`m getting 0 when I return this from my ViewController :

```
NSLog(@"%i",self.view.frame.size.height);
```

In Interface builder, the View it's managing is occupying the entire screen .

Help ?

Comment: Height is a float.  Try using %f or %d instead.  If that doesn't work, how are you autosizing?  Check the ruler tab in IB and look for "Autosizing".  What is selected?

Comment: @Mishie: Not `%d`, that is for decimal integers, just like `%i`.

Comment: ah yeah, float is returning 460.000.

Comment: Also I can`t seem to apply my animation for some reason, updated the code

Comment: Make that a new question please as your original one seems to be solved - this is not a forum but a site focused on single questions. @Mishie: Seems like you should add the `%f` part as an answer.

Comment: @Georg using %d also works for floats.  And you don't always get the .000 after, which is sometimes nice.

Comment: @Mishie: Euh, no. See the [format specifiers](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) - `%d` and `%i` are the same. If it does the right thing that's just incidental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Height is a float. Use `%f` to log it.